# Generalization of a theorem of Frobenius

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

> If $G$ is a finite group, $H\leq G$ a subgroup, and $n$ divides $|G|$, then $n$ divides $[G:N_{G}(H)]$ times the number of elements $g\in G$ for which $|\langle H,g\rangle|$ is a divisor of $n$.

This appears as Theorem 6.1 of [van der Lee - Elementary proof of a theorem of Hawkes, Isaacs, and Özaydin](https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.00513). I was not able to find a source myself, and I wondered whether the result was new. Any references for this result?

(When $H=1$, this is just Frobenius' theorem, by which the number of $g\in G$ with $g^{n}=1$ is a multiple of $n$, for $n\mid |G|$.)

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1907.00513

Comment: it would have been better to put the link to arxiv paper already in the question...

Comment: I have edited in your remarks from the comments.  Please feel free to revert or correct if you like.

Comment: I apologise for the edit; I tried only to incorporate the information from the comments.  Of course, please feel free to revert or correct if the edit is not welcome.

Comment: @LSpice, sorry, no problem.

Comment: @MatthévanderLee: I don't know if it helps but Theorem 4.5 in  the Hawkes-Isaacs-Özaydin paper states that $$\mu(H,G) \in \frac{|N_G(H):H |}{|G:G'H |_0} \mathbb{Z}.$$ with $|n|_0$ the square-free part of $n$, and $G'$ the derived subgroup of $G$.

Comment: @SebastienPalcoux, by the theorem of Hawkes-Isaacs-Özaydin,  $\mu(H,G)$ is even in $[N_{G}(H):H]\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @MatthévanderLee: No, take $H=1$ and $G=C_p$ (with $p$ prime). Then, $\mu(H,G) = -1$ whereas $|N_{G}(H):H| = |C_p : 1| = p$, but $-1 \not \in p \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Oops, my mistake...